# How to alter the welcome message after successfull registration

Tags: 7

A message is shown upon successful registration, with the following contents:

> A welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail address

I would like to change the content of that message and use a different HTML structure, e.g.:

```
 <p>Thanks for registering</p>
 <a href="#">continue</a>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this and much more similar things with [LoginToboggan module](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), from module page:

> The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal login system in an external module by offering the following features and usability improvements:
>   Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail address.
>   Allow users to login immediately.
>   Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.
>   The module provides two login block options: One uses JavaScript to display the form within the block immediately upon clicking "log in". The other brings the user to a separate page, but returns the user to their original page upon login.
>   Customize the registration form with two e-mail fields to ensure accuracy.
>   Optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.
>   Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.
>   Optionally display a user message indicating a successful login.
>   Optionally combine both the login and registration form on one page.
>   Optionally have unvalidated users purged from the system at a pre-defined interval (please read the CAVEATS section of INSTALL.txt for important information on configuring this feature!).
>   Integrates with Rules module to do various tasks when a user validates via email validation process (see http://drupal.org/node/880904 for an example)

UI settings are simple and straight forward, and are located in admin/config/people/accounts